# I am getting error when I create data and transfer that to db, in laravel

Tags: laravel

This is my controller

```
  public function store_chapters()
  {
    $data = request()->validate([
        "name" => ['required'],
        "video" => ['required','file','mimes:mp4'],
        "description" => ['required'],
    ]); //dd($data);

    $video = request('video')->store('uploads','public'); //dd($video);

    subjects()->chapters()->create([
        'chapter_name' => $data['name'],
        'description' => $data['description'],
        'video' => $video,
    ]);

    return redirect('show_index');
 }
```

video uplod section work perfectly,  but my problem is, you can see above functions called 
`subjects()` and `chapters()`. I have to insert these data into chapters table which contain the following.

id subject_id chapter_name video description status

and I have a separate table called subjects which holds `id`, `subject_name`, `status`.

there are some subjects in this table, and when I add a chapter belongs to particular subject which should be added in chapters table with proper `subject_id` but it wont work my model are,
**Subject.php**

```
class Subject extends Model
{
   protected $guarded = [];

   public function chapters()
   {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subject');
  }
}
```

**Chapter.php**

```
class Chapter extends Model
{
      protected $guarded = [];

  public function subjects()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Chapter', 'subject_id'); 
  }
}
```

please help me to figure it out the issue with advance thanks..

Comment: you can't insert data like this, subjects()->chapters()->create([
        'chapter_name' => $data['name'],
        'description' => $data['description'],
        'video' => $video,
    ]);
use this doc, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserts

Comment: then how if you know the answer please share..one subject has many chapters and chapters under one subject

Comment: I have solved the answer..thank you for your valueble time..

Comment: <input type="hidden"  name="subject" value="{{$subject->id}}"> in view page                        $chapter = Chapter::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'description' => $data['description'],
            'video' => $video,
            'subject_id' => request('subject'),
            'status' => 1,
        ]); in controller

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden"  name="subject" value="{{$subject->id}}">
```

this should be added in the appropriate view page

```
$chapter = Chapter::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'description' => $data['description'],
        'video' => $video,
        'subject_id' => request('subject'),
        'status' => 1,
]);
```

and the subject_id should be get from input field using by attribute name..